# SEGFAULT in -O3 mode?

Tags: c++, gcc, optimization, segmentation-fault

I summarized my problem to the following short program.

It causes SEGFAULT in -O3 mode only (-O2 works fine).
According to `gdb` it happens at `*f = 0` line.

```
#include <iostream>

void func1(int s, int t)
{
        char* buffer = new char[s + t*sizeof(float)];
        if (!buffer)
        {
            std::cout << "new failed\n";
            return;
        }
        float* f = (float*)(buffer + s);
        for (int i = 0; i < t; ++i)
        {
            *f = 0;
            //std::cout << i << std::endl; // if uncomment this line everything will work fine
            ++f;
        }
        delete [] buffer;
        std::cout << "done\n";
}

int main()
{
        int s = 31, t = 12423138;
        std::cout << s << " " << t << std::endl;
        func1(s, t);
        return 0;
}
```

Please let me know, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: That is a gross violation of [the strict aliasing rule](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/98650/what-is-the-strict-aliasing-rule). As for the crash it's probably because you access unaligned data. Due to the aliasing problem it might not help, but try to compile with more warnings (e.g.`-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`) and see if it tells you anything.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I compiled this code on MSVC with -W4 -Wx, and it compiled fine.

Comment: AFAIK MSVC++ never assume strict aliasing rules and doesn't make any optimisations dependent on these rules.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius I [compiled it with clang](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cb5a83ec94c8089f) and it does indeed complain that *"cast from 'char *' to 'float *' increases required alignment from 1 to 4"*.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I compiled it with -Wall option and it didn't complain, but I'll try it with -Wextra -pedantic. Thanks for pointing out strict aliasing rule violation

Comment: This is what happens when you engage in hackery.

Comment: It seems that g++ doesn't complain about anything even with `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` options enabled. The program doesn't crash with`--no-strict-aliasing`, but what should the one do before resorting to this option? 
In real life, I have a file on disk, which I would like to read into a buffer first, and then interpret some binary data from the buffer

Comment: I've changed the code to [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/735783b1e72b2f7c). Does it break strict aliasing rule? At least clang doesn't complain about alignment anymore

Comment: Solutions are provided in the StackOverflow thread mentioned in the first comment, e.g. a union.

Comment: @MartinZabel Yes, I've seen that, thx, but as I understood union requires a strict message format, whereas in my case, there may be strings of variable length inside that buffer

Comment: I cannot reproduce it here. But, the actual problem should be, that the compiler moves the `delete buffer[]` before the clearing loop. How this would apply to your file I/O scenario, I cannot imagine yet.

Comment: In -O3 it crashes even when that line with `delete` commented

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The source of SEGFAULT was not solely in violation of the strict aliasing rule, as the problem persisted even with  -fno-strict-aliasing flag.

It was indeed accessing unaligned memory, but not as simple as that. As modern processors, generally allow unaligned memory access and there is even not much of an overhead nowadays. I've done some benchmarking and didn't observe a big difference in algined vs unaligned read on my Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2680 v2 @ 2.80GHz. Also there are [some](http://lemire.me/blog/2012/05/31/data-alignment-for-speed-myth-or-reality/) very similar (and more or less recent) results in the web.

My problem was that `-O3` mode enables `-ftree-vectorize` flag, therefore my `for` cycle was vectorized (as I could see using `-ftree-vectorizer-verbose` flag). And (AFAIU) there is no support (yet?) for unaligned memory access using **vectorized** instructions, so there was a runtime exception.

[This article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/pa-dalign/) helped me out a lot in understanding theory, though it seems that today unaligned memory access is not as harmful as it was, though still tricky